# angular-resizable-element - click event is not emitted on Firefox and Safari

Tags: javascript, angular, onclick, click

I use angular-resizable-element v. 3.2.3 npm library to make resizable divs. I made (click) binding on those elements. The problem is that click event is emitted on Chrome but is not emitted on Firefox (v. 65.0.1) and Safari (v. 10.1.2) - the bound method is not triggered. What causes this situation?
This is the fragment of html where I create resizable divs.

```
<div
*ngFor="let block of blocks; index as i"
id="resizable-{{i}}"
class="resizable"
mwlResizable
[ngStyle]="{'width.px': block.width * cellWidth, 'height.px': block.height * cellHeight, 'top.px': block.y * cellHeight, 'left.px': block.x * cellWidth}"
[enableGhostResize]="true"
[resizeSnapGrid]="{left: cellWidth, right: cellWidth}"
[resizeEdges]="{bottom: false, right: true, top: false, left: true}"
(resizeEnd)="onResizeEnd(i, $event)"
(resizeStart)="onResizeStart(i, $event)"
(resizing)="onResizing(i, $event)"
(click)="onClick(i, $event)"
[validateResize]="component.validate"
#resizable>
```